# Poker pre-flop probability training tool

Tags: texas-hold-em, probability

Is there a freeware, better FLOSS, online or preferably offline trainer for preflop probabilities. I imagine different play modes with entering percentages under measurement of time resulting in statistics on accuracy and time, or multiple choice.

I could just click on a probability table and do some "vocabulary learning", but a trainer as described has a much more convenient motivation and useful statistics imo.

I'm so specific about the modes because if there's none, I might take the time to program one myself.

Comment: I don't know such software. I understand learning the preflop percentages with an online trainer can be more efficient and fun, but it should not take too long to know all the matchups within an error range of a couple of percentages. I don't think you need much more accuracy, so unless there is software already available, programming one yourself might not be your best option.

Comment: @paparazzo This comment is not helping if you don't explain what you don't understand, i.e. show a logical mistake, misunderstood terms, etc.

Comment: @paparazzo I don't understand why you post such a comment (twice) if you have >5000 points and clearly understood how SE sites work. At least allow me to improve my question.

Comment: @KarlRichter If you don't want to expand the question then fine.  No problem.